# Minimum cost to convert all elements of an array to zero?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, data-structures, dynamic-programming

We are given an **array of integers**, and we want to convert all elements to **0** with **minimum total cost**.

We can do 3 following operations on array elements :

1. Decrease a element by 1 with cost **B**
2. Increase a element by 1 with cost **L**
3. Decrease a element by 1 in loc i and increase by 1 in loc j by 1 with cost **|i-j| * M**

> **Sample testcase:**

**Input**:

```
  [2, -2, 1, 0, -1, -1]
  B = 20, L = 150, M = 30
```

**Output**:

```
270
```

**Explanation :**

```
Increase by 2 at loc 1 and decrease by 2 at loc 0, cost incurred : 2 * |1 - 0| * 30 = 60
Increase by 1 at loc 4 and decrease by 1 at loc 2, cost incurred : 1 * |4 - 2| * 30 = 60
Increase by 1 at loc 5, cost incurred : 1 * 150 = 150
So total min cost: 60 + 60 + 150 = 270
```

**Constraints :**

> **1 < N < 10^5**
> **-10 < A[i] < 10**
> **1 < B, L < 10^8**
> **1 < M < 10^3**

> **How can we solve this problem efficiently ?**

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the problem, there are a few things to think about. Which operations are the most effective at reducing cost. There are three options, B, L and n*M, where n is the "distance" between two elements.
The n*M is worth using when the cost is less than an L and B operation (150 + 20) or n = 5. Because  5 * M = 150. The only senario to use this however, is when there is a positive and negative element, at most 5 elements apart. So this would be the first test. If these criteria are met, this case will produce the least cost.

The next best case decrease with cost B. Where the elements is positive, and no negative element is within +-5 elements.

The last case is to increase with cost L. Inverse of the criteria above for B.

Testing all of this could be done in multiple ways. The way I am thinking of right now is to create a queue that has eleven elements. Test the middle element with the criterion above, then pop and push FIFO, traversing through the array. These are just my initial thoughts to get you started.

Comment: I was thinking about this problem too, but I came to the conclusion that it is harder than it seems. E.g. take this example [2, 0, -2, 2] and M a lot smaller than L and B. Now making the first 2 and the -2 to 0 with M operations is a lot better than using L and B operations to do this, but still not the best. You can't just go through the array from left to right I think.

Comment: Maybe store the distances between two possible elements as you move through the entire array, and only perform the M cost operation on the smallest distance. Then go through the array again.

Comment: Yes that would be one way to solve it. Unfortunatley it is O(n^2).